# split items of batch into multiple categories

Tags: java

I have a batch job that contains a lot of items. I need to split these items into 4 categories - `1,2` category should be moved to a separate jobs as is; `3,4` categories job be additionally checked on validness and split into separate jobs - invalid items should be moved to a separate jobs.

Roughly diagram of the expected flow looks like this

[image]

For now I come up the prototype that looks like this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.items = Arrays.asList(
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_1, "1"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_2, "2"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_3, "3"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_1, "4"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_2, "5"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_3, "6"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_4, "7"),
            new Item(ItemCategory.CAT_4, "8")
        );

        /*
            [1:CAT_1, 4:CAT_1]
            [2:CAT_2, 5:CAT_2]
            [6:CAT_3]
            [8:CAT_4]
            [3:CAT_3, 7:CAT_4]
        */
        List<List<Item>> categorizedItems = job.items.parallelStream().collect(
            () -> Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()), // last item is error aggregator
            (list, item) -> {
                switch (item.category) {
                    case CAT_1: list.get(0).add(item); break;
                    case CAT_2: list.get(1).add(item); break;
                    case CAT_3: {

                        if (isValid(item.id)) {
                            list.get(2).add(item);
                        } else {
                            list.get(4).add(item);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case CAT_4: {

                        if (isValid(item.id)) {
                            list.get(3).add(item);
                        } else {
                            list.get(4).add(item);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            (list1, list2) -> {
                list1.get(0).addAll(list2.get(0));
                list1.get(1).addAll(list2.get(1));
                list1.get(2).addAll(list2.get(2));
                list1.get(3).addAll(list2.get(3));
                list1.get(4).addAll(list2.get(4));
            }
        );
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String id) {
        return Integer.valueOf(id) % 2 == 0;
    }

    public static class Item {
        ItemCategory category;
        String id;

        Item(ItemCategory category, String id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.category = category;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + ":" + category;
        }
    }

    public enum ItemCategory {
        CAT_1, CAT_2, CAT_3, CAT_4;
    }

    public static class Job {
        List<Item> items;
    }
}
```

Is it a good a idea to do everything in a single stream? Or for example it is better split into 4 categories first and then process 3,4 categories separately?

Comment: Re: “is it better split into 4 categories first?”   Does the order of the items items that end up in category 5 matter?  If you split the list into 4 groups, you’ve lost the relative ordering of invalid category 3 and invalid category 4 items.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried running this without the `parallelStream`? If you have a small data set, parallelism can be an overhead.

Comment: @AJNeufeld no it is not. category 5 is something akin Dead Letter Queue - as long as it contains right elements everything is ok.

Comment: @IEatBagels I will have thousands of items in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Collector` is reinventing the wheel.  There already exists a collector which partitions the collected items into groups: [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)), which you could use something like:

```
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        item -> (item.category == CAT_3 || item.category == CAT_4) && !isValid(item.id)
                     ? CAT_5 : item.category)
    )
)
```

Of course, this will return a `Map<ItemCategory, List<Item>>`.  You can transform this back to a list of lists, if needed.

And of course, you would need to add the `CAT_5` to the `ItemCategory` enum.  Alternately, you could use `null` at the category 5 key, if you don't mind `null` as a key value, but be warned that it will make some people's skin crawl.

---

If the order of the items in the all of the groups (as opposed to just the Category 5 group) does not matter, then [`groupingByConcurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent(java.util.function.Function)) will give better parallel stream performance.

Comment: But if I aggregate it into the map, then to process 3,4 category I will have to get them and store non valid items later into some other map or list?

Comment: The classifier function, above, groups non-valid category 3,4 items into the map under category 5.  Only valid category 3 items are stored in the map under category 3, and only valid category 4 items are stored in the map under category 4.

Comment: did not know about `groupingByConcurrent`